# What is the form1.resx file ? Can we delete this and still run error free?

Tags: c#, forms, c#-3.0, resx

I want to know what this **form1.resx** button is all about. I read up this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/Vsexpressvcs/thread/daf4be8a-5fb7-4c54-8152-b9afd340f4c4)  and got to know more about the Program.cs(main() file), form1.cs(logical code) and form1.Designer.cs(UI related code) but not the **form1.resx** file. Is there any harm if I delete it. What is the purpose of the form1.resx file ??

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to open the file in a text editor - preferable with XML highlighting. You will see a very well commented XML file with information about the form's resources. My understanding is that if you delete the file, external resources associated with the form will be lost.